# How does CMake's dependency extraction work?

Tags: c++, cmake

I noticed that the recent version of [CMake release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/release/3.20.html?highlight=compiler%20generated%20dependencies#generators) has a line about a new feature:

> Makefile Generators, for some toolchains, now use the compiler to extract implicit dependencies while compiling source files.

This sounds like a cool feature, but I couldn't figure out how to actually use it. A quick search didn't return any obvious documentation. Does anyone here know more about how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

This is referring to implicit *header* dependencies. GCC, Clang, and several other compilers have a flag for writing files listing these dependencies during the first compile. CMake then points the generated build systems to these files so they can load the extra dependencies during incremental builds.

This is all automatic with CMake and requires no special action on your part. It can, however be *disabled* by setting a special variable to FALSE, `CMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER`.

Here is the merge request that introduced this feature: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/5528

For further reading, see the documentation for the `-MMD` flag on GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: Wasn't it used in previous cmake versions? `have a flag for writing files listing these dependencies during the first compile` exactly, this feature has been used since always.  Why do you think this feature wasn't used? How does the current cmake version differ in that usage?

Comment: Old CMake versions, AFAIK, had their own implementation of dependency scanning. That's how `add_custom_command`'s `IMPLICIT_DEPENDS` option worked.

Comment: I'm aware of GCC's `-M` flags. But this announcement reads like cmake has recently acquired the ability to use those, and I'm trying to figure out how to utilize it.

Comment: Re: "I'm trying to figure out how to utilize it" -- that's already in my answer! You don't have to do _anything_. CMake takes care of that automatically.